# Calculate the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\frac {(\tan(x)-x)^2} {(\ln(x+1)-x)^3} $

Tags: calculus, limits

> Calculate: $$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\frac {(\tan(x)-x)^2} {(\ln(x+1)-x)^3} $$

So if we expand Taylor polynomials we get:

$$\frac {(x+{x^3\over3}+o(x^3)-x)^2}{(x-{x^2\over2}+o(x^2)-x)^3}=\frac {({x^3\over3}+o(x^3))^2}{(-{x^2\over2}+o(x^2))^3}$$

How do I continue from here ?

Another related question, what is the best way to memorize the taylor polynomial of all of the common elementary functions ?

Comment: You are missing a minus sign in the denominator. Numerator and denominator have the same leading order, $x^6$. Divide both by that.

Comment: Just drop all the ${} + o(...)$ since they are too small to be considered; and proceed from there.

Comment: @user49685 Is it formal to just drop them because they're small ?

Comment: @GinKin: Yes, you can drop them as long as the new expression obtained by dropping them, doesn't belong to any indeterminate forms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it should be$$\frac {({x^3\over3}+o(x^5))^2}{(-{x^2\over2}+o(x^3))^3}$$
and so
$$\frac {x^6({1\over3}+o(x^2))^2}{x^6(-{1\over2}+o(x))^3}\to \frac{({1\over3})^2}{({-1\over2})^3}  \ \ \text{as }\ \ x\to 0$$

Comment: you are completely right, thank you

Comment: Isn't it necessary to include some explanation when removing the little os ?

Answer (score 1):

This is based on two standard limits $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\tan x - x}{x^{3}} =\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sec^{2}x - 1}{3x^{2}}\text{ (by LHR)} = \frac{1}{3}\lim_{x \to 0}\left(\frac{\tan x}{x}\right)^{2} = \frac{1}{3}$$ and $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\log(1 + x) - x}{x^{2}} = \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{1 + x} - 1}{2x}\text{ (by LHR)} = -\frac{1}{2}$$ Clearly we now have $$\begin{aligned}L &= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(\tan x - x)^{2}}{\{\log(1 + x) - x\}^{3}}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{\tan x - x}{x^{3}}\right)^{2}}{\left(\dfrac{\log(1 + x) - x}{x^{2}}\right)^{3}}\text{ (dividing Nr and Dr by }x^{6})\\
&= \dfrac{(1/3)^{2}}{(-1/2)^{3}}= -\frac{8}{9}\end{aligned}$$

Comment: How can you substitute these two limits and why the curly braces ?

Comment: @GinKin: About substitution you know the rule $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)/g(x) = \lim_{x \to a}f(x)/\lim_{x \to a}g(x)$ provided both limits exist and denominator limit is non-zero. And the curly braces are for clarity. I would change them to normal parentheses. Don't worry for that.

Comment: I still don't see how can you substitute them so $\lim (\tan x - x)^{2}=\lim\dfrac{\tan x - x}{x^{3}}$ and the same for the other one...

Comment: @GinKin: I have divided numerator and denominator by $x^{6}$ and then made substitution.

Comment: I get it now. This won't always work right ?

Comment: Well in this case the division by $x^{6}$ led to some pretty famous limits in both numerator and denominator and that's why it worked.